# Remain same tab after page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I am using jquery for tabs. I want to stay on same tab after page reloading.
I have used different solutions for that but cannot get result.
Below is my HTML code of tabs.

```
<div style="margin: 0px;" class="ui-slider-tabs-list-container">
    <ul class="ui-slider-tabs-list">
        <li class="selected" style="height: 32px;"><a style="height: 32px;" href="#frontprodesc">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li style="height: 32px;"><a style="height: 32px;" href="#frontproprop">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li style="height: 32px;"><a style="height: 32px;" href="#frontproimages">Tab 3</a></li>
        <li style="height: 32px;"><a style="height: 32px;" href="#frontproapproval">Tab 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And here is the tab content code

```
<div class="ui-slider-tabs-content-container">
   <div class="ui-slider-tab-content selected" id="frontprodesc">Tab 1 Content</div>
   <div class="ui-slider-tab-content" id="frontproprop">Tab 2 Content</div>
   <div class="ui-slider-tab-content" id="frontproimages">Tab 3 Content</div>
   <div class="ui-slider-tab-content" id="frontproapproval">Tab 4 Content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Read about [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

Comment: Please do a search before asking your question.

Comment: Hi Praveen Kumar, I have read many questions but can't find proper solution for code. Kindly remove duplicate mark from my question.